# difference in syntax when doing kuberentes deployments related operations

Tags: kubernetes

What is the difference between the following syntax usage:

kubectl get deployments

kubectl get deployment.apps

kubectl get deployment.v1.apps

There are references to deployment.v1.apps and deployment.apps in the documentation specially when talking about rollouts and upgrades.
For example:
To see the Deployment rollout status, run kubectl rollout status deployment.v1.apps/nginx-deployment

For example:
Let's update the nginx Pods to use the nginx:1.16.1 image instead of the nginx:1.14.2 image.

kubectl --record deployment.apps/nginx-deployment set image deployment.v1.apps/nginx-deployment nginx=nginx:1.16.1

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference. They show you in [examples](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/) different ways to access the resource.

This is the reference to app/v1 api that you can see in [example nginx deployment](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/website/master/content/en/examples/controllers/nginx-deployment.yaml):

**apiVersion: apps/v1**

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx-deployment
  labels:
    app: nginx
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: nginx
        image: nginx:1.14.2
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
```

You can use shorten way like `kubectl get deployments` either longer ones you provided in the question.

However, its obvious, you cant use  e.g app/v2

```
kubectl get deployment.v2.apps/nginx-deployment
error: the server doesn't have a resource type "deployment"
```